# React refs - accessing DOM nodes using refs

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I'm trying to access DOM nodes of a react component using refs. I've already seen a lot of example doing that. I decided to make my first app using React, and then I was stuck resolving this issue.

```
onDivHover:function()
{
    this.refs.myslider.getDOMNode().value = 20;
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="sliderBox" OnMouseOver={this.onDivHover()}>
            <input ref="myslider" type="range" min={this.props.minimum} max={this.props.maximum} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

See, in the code I tried to change the value of slider using refs. If I comment that one line inside `onDivHover`, I'm able to load the app successfully. The error which is coming is React is unable to resolve `myslider` inside `onDivHover`.

This seems crazy, as I've seen many examples using that. I might be missing something very basic and important. Please help in resolving this.

Comment: Try `onMouseOver={this.onDivHover}`

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Such a silly one! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React events expect a function, so you should pass a reference, not execute it:

```
onMouseOver={this.onDivHover}
```